# What type of value does one LSTM block produce? Is it a number in range [0;1] or a vector with numbers in range [0;1]?

Tags: deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have read different papers and tutorials about LSTM neural nets and I can't understand this thing. If you look at this article https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.08144.pdf at page 4 you will see architecture of Google’s Neural Machine Translation system which has 8 layers of LSTM neurons. Let's discuss certain moment of time "t" so we are interested only in 8 LSTM neurons. If first LSTM neuron returns number then second LSTM neuron takes this number as an input(SO NOT A VECTOR that is strange). On the other hand if LSTM neuron produces vector as an output the things get more weird. Help please.